# use python string.split() with a line of utf-8 encoding

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, split, tokenize

I have a utf-8 encoded text file and i want to tokenize each line using split as a simple tokenizer.
the code is like here:

```
import codecs
file = codecs.open(fileAddress, 'r', 'utf-8')
line = file.readline()
file.close()
line.split()
```

This doesn't split the utf-8 string as i use on ascii files. I want a line like "hi i am here" which is in utf-8 encoding to become a list of tokens like ["hi", "i", "am", "here"] which is easy with ascii using line.split().

Is there any simple solution to this problem?

Comment: This should work just fine, provided your data has got regular whitespace in it. Can you show us a sample line for which it doesn't work?

Comment: And note that `line` is a unicode string; that it was once decoded from UTF-8 data has no bearing on your splitting problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Martijn Pieters,Your code should work fine, provided your file have regular spaces as separators. The only difference from the result you are expecting is that the tokens will of the type *unicode* and not *str*.

There are some other unicode characters used to represent whitespaces http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode, maybe this is causing the mess, even the readline can be problematic if this is the case...